# python pandas: Compare consective rows, update/concatenate cell of first row in consecutive duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates, rows

On a DataFrame sorted by date, then by record number (df.sort(['Service Date', 'Record Number']), I'm trying to:

1. Compare <s>'Service Date'</s> 'Record Number' to the row beneath
2. Then append/concatenate/update the contents of 'Desc' in the first row with the contents of 'Desc' in the second row if the rows are duplicates.
3. Append a third, fourth, etc. 'Desc' as necessary.

I want to end up with all 'Desc' contents of the consecutive duplicates to end up in the first instance of the duplicates. Here's the code I have so far. I've tried .shift(1) within the for loop, to no avail:

```
import pandas

with open('ALL.CSV') as inc:
    indf = pandas.read_csv(inc, usecols=['Record Number', 'Service Date', 'Desc'], parse_dates=True)
    indf['Service Date'] = pandas.to_datetime(indf['Service Date'])
    indf.sort(['Service Date', 'Record Number'], inplace=True)
    indf['NUM'] = indf['Record Number'].shift(1)
    msk = indf['NUM'] == indf['Record Number']
    indf['MASK'] = msk
#    print(indf)
#    print(indf.dtypes)
#    print(msk)
    for i, row in indf.iterrows():
        if row['MASK'] == False:
            print('Unique.', row['Record Number'], row['Service Date'], row['Desc'])
        else:
            print('Dupe...', row['Record Number'], row['Service Date'], row['Desc'])
```

Sample data:

```
Record Number,Service Date,Desc
746611,05/26/2014,jiber
361783,05/27/2014,manawyddan
231485,06/02/2014,montespan
254004,06/03/2014,peshawar
369750,06/09/2014,cochleate
757701,06/10/2014,verticity
586983,06/16/2014,psychotherapist
643669,06/17/2014,discreation
252213,06/23/2014,hemiacetal
863001,06/24/2014,jiber
563798,06/30/2014,manawyddan
229226,07/01/2014,montespan
772189,07/07/2014,peshawar
412939,07/08/2014,cochleate
230209,07/14/2014,verticity
723012,07/15/2014,psychotherapist
455138,07/21/2014,discreation
605876,07/22/2014,hemiacetal
565893,07/28/2014,jiber
760420,07/29/2014,manawyddan
667002,05/27/2014,montespan
676209,06/17/2014,peshawar
828060,06/24/2014,cochleate
582821,07/01/2014,verticity
275503,07/15/2014,psychotherapist
667002,05/26/2014,discreation
676209,06/02/2014,hemiacetal
828060,06/09/2014,jiber
667002,06/10/2014,manawyddan
676209,06/17/2014,montespan
828060,06/23/2014,peshawar
667002,06/24/2014,cochleate
676209,06/30/2014,verticity
828060,07/21/2014,psychotherapist
667002,07/28/2014,discreation
676209,05/27/2014,hemiacetal
828060,06/03/2014,jiber
667002,06/10/2014,manawyddan
676209,06/16/2014,montespan
828060,06/24/2014,peshawar
667002,07/01/2014,cochleate
676209,07/07/2014,verticity
828060,07/28/2014,psychotherapist
667002,07/29/2014,discreation
828060,06/09/2014,hemiacetal
667002,06/10/2014,jiber
676209,06/17/2014,manawyddan
828060,06/23/2014,montespan
667002,06/24/2014,peshawar
676209,06/30/2014,cochleate
828060,07/21/2014,verticity
828060,06/09/2014,psychotherapist
667002,06/10/2014,discreation
676209,06/17/2014,hemiacetal
828060,06/23/2014,jiber
667002,06/24/2014,manawyddan
676209,06/30/2014,montespan
```

EDIT: I think I may have figured it out. Anyone see a better way to go about this? Thanks!

```
import pandas

with open('ALL.CSV') as inc:
    indf = pandas.read_csv(inc, usecols=['Record Number', 'Service Date', 'Desc'], parse_dates=True)
    indf['Service Date'] = pandas.to_datetime(indf['Service Date'])
    indf.sort(['Service Date', 'Record Number'], inplace=True)
    indf['NUM'] = indf['Record Number'].shift(1)
    msk = indf['NUM'] == indf['Record Number']
    indf['MASK'] = msk
    indf.reset_index(inplace=True)
#    print(indf)
#    print(indf.dtypes)
#    print(msk)
    cnt = -1
    for i, row in indf.iterrows():
        cnt += 1
        if row['MASK'] == False:
            cnt = i
#            print(i, cnt, 'Unique.', row['Record Number'], row['Service Date'], row['Desc'])
        else:
            cnt -= 1
#            print(i, cnt, 'Dupe...', row['Record Number'], row['Service Date'], row['Desc'])
#            print(indf['Desc'][cnt], indf['Desc'][i])
            indf['Desc'][cnt] = '. '.join([indf['Desc'][cnt], indf['Desc'][i]])
#    print(indf)
    indf.drop_duplicates(['Service Date', 'Record Number'], inplace=True)
    del(indf['index'])
    del(indf['NUM'])
    del(indf['MASK'])
    indf.to_csv('ALL_fixed.csv', date_format='%m/%d/%Y', index=False)
```

Comment: what will happen to the record data? drop it?

Comment: The duplicates will be dropped, yes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want one column 'desc' which has all the values in it (which is what I gather from your question, then you can just group the data on 'date' and aggregate it by joining all the 'desc' together into one string:

```
#this is the aggregation function
def desc_concat(x):
    return ", ".join(x)
# apply it to data grouped by date
df.groupby(['date', 'record']).agg({'desc' : desc_concat})
```

Comment: I apologize, I'm comparing 'Record Number' for each 'Service Date', I made a typo in the original question. 'Record Number' can appear on separate 'Service Date', and I only want to concatenate the 'Desc' of duplicate 'Record Number' per 'Service Date'.

Comment: In that case just groupby date and redcord. See updated answer